# Can't understand code handling mouseevent

Tags: javascript

I'm relatively new to JavaScript and can't understand the code from the book `Eloquent Javascript`. It is used to fire mousemove not frequenter than 500ms, but I can't understand what is null here for.

```
let scheduled = null;
window.addEventListener("mousemove", event => {
    if (!scheduled) {//*if scheduled ==null
        setTimeout(() => {
           document.body.textContent =
           `Mouse at ${scheduled.pageX}, ${scheduled.pageY}`;
           scheduled = null;
        }, 500);
    }
    scheduled = event;
});
```

Comment: null is the same as undefined it is just the person writing the program sets scheduled to 'undefined' what means nothing happend yet and when something happens scheduled will not be null or undefined anymore for the next 500ms it will become the event.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first time code starts the value of `scheduled` is null and when the event is fired, it will go into `if` condition and wait for `500 ms`, and in the meantime, the function will set `scheduled` to some value. and after the `500ms` wait time is over it will again set `scheduled` as `null`.

So every time `scheduled` is set to `null` thing happen. and when things start to happen it changed `scheduled` to some value or no other things can happen.

Don't be confused.
Let's say, mousemove event is fired 100 times in 1 second. So at the time when 1st mouseevent is fired, we are asking system to don't execute anything if things already `scheduled`. and with the above code, we know that things remain `scheduled` for `500ms`. With that, mousemove events will still be executed 100 times, but the code that is performed by mousemove event will be execute twice in one second, instead of 100.

Answer (score 1):

You dont have to keep the value as "null". It cal also be any other types based on the logic(such as a boolean). See the below example with boolean -

```
let scheduled = false;
window.addEventListener("mousemove", event => {
    if (!scheduled) {//*if not scheduled
        setTimeout(() => {
           document.body.textContent =
           `Mouse at ${event.pageX}, ${event.pageY}`;
           scheduled = false;
           console.log("Counter restarting")
        }, 3000);
    }

    scheduled = true;
});
```

At first when the program starts, "scheduled" flag is set to false - indicating that there is no current timeout set for 3 seconds. So we set then timeout and set the "scheduled flag" to true. Once the timeout is reached, the current mouse position is printed and the "scheduled" flag is set as false and the process repeats.